# Convert frontmatter markdown to html on gatsby.js

Tags: gatsby

Is there an easy way to convert frontmatter content to html on Gatsby, without just setting that content as html itself on the markdown?

So in this example:

```
---
about:
description: >-
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in maximus lorem. Sed non neque eget augue eleifend ultricies ac cursus mauris. Aliquam sed lectus at ex ullamcorper euismod in a quam. Donec convallis nisl nec risus suscipit placerat. Proin bibendum, tellus aliquam condimentum vulputate, lacus augue egestas magna, quis iaculis nis


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [Apply](asd.das.com) lorm sadf.
image: /img/new_screen.png
title: Everything you need to grow your audience.
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in maximus lorem. Sed non neque eget augue eleifend ultricies ac cursus mauris. Aliquam sed lectus at ex ullamcorper euismod in a quam. Donec convallis nisl nec risus suscipit placerat. Proin bibendum, tellus aliquam condimentum vulputate, lacus augue egestas magna, quis iaculis nisi ligula at ante. Duis sagittis suscipit felis, id posuere massa posuere et. Phasellus non diam consectetur, eleifend magna ac, facilisis metus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent massa ipsum, pulvinar finibus ante
```

What's the best way to access "description" as html?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an easy way to do what you're asking.  As an alternative, you might break up your markdown into two files, one for the description and the other for the content.

description.md

```
---
pageId: description
groupId: home
---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in maximus lorem. Sed non neque eget augue eleifend ultricies ac cursus mauris. Aliquam sed lectus at ex ullamcorper euismod in a quam. Donec convallis nisl nec risus suscipit placerat. Proin bibendum, tellus aliquam condimentum vulputate, lacus augue egestas magna, quis iaculis nis


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [Apply](asd.das.com) lorm sadf.
```

main.md

```
---
pageId: main
groupId: home
image: /img/new_screen.png
title: Everything you need to grow your audience.  
---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in maximus lorem. Sed non neque eget augue eleifend ultricies ac cursus mauris. Aliquam sed lectus at ex ullamcorper euismod in a quam. Donec convallis nisl nec risus suscipit placerat. Proin bibendum, tellus aliquam condimentum vulputate, lacus augue egestas magna, quis iaculis nisi ligula at ante. Duis sagittis suscipit felis, id posuere massa posuere et. Phasellus non diam consectetur, eleifend magna ac, facilisis metus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent massa ipsum, pulvinar finibus ante
```

Depending on your needs, you can get all related information about the "home" group with the corresponding graphql query:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {groupId: {eq: "home"}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        html
        frontmatter {
          pageId
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access your markdown via Gatsby's graphql layer through `gatsby-transformer-remark`, which is the recommended way you can just fetch it like so in a graphql query (random example):

```
allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
      limit: 1000
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          html
          id
          frontmatter {
            date
            path
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then you can access it through the props in your component, e.g.:
`props.data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.description`.